# Caching asp.net page response on client side

Tags: asp.net, caching, client, response

I am trying to cache asp.net page response on client Browser by adding following cache headers

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Public);
```

With the above headers it is not working.. May I know what else to be added?

I am using jquery from client side to get the page response

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What happens if you try to set the cache declaratively?

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="6000" VaryByParam="None"%>
```

Comment: Looks like the OutputCache declaration is working, I will be validating across different browsers. I am not sure when to use Cache headers that I mentioned in the above question. Any info on that would be helpful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OutputCache caches on the *Server* side.  The Questioner was asking about Caching on the *Client* side.  Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx